# Why is EXTJS download PICKER related files when I have no reference to PICKER anywhere in my app?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I build an app with sencha cmd - "sencha build production" and when I run my app through Fiddler I can see it downloading /ext/classic/classic/src/picker/Date.js and /ext/classic/classic/src/form/field/Date.js, and also in my classic.json file that gets compiled I can see references to pickers in there too.

I'm not "requiring" those classes anywhere in my app, so I thought CMD was only spuposed to include files required for the app to run?  Am I doing something wrong or do I have to specifically "exclude" files in build.xml that I don't want included in the build?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sencha Cmd builds a component tree, starting with application and adding required components until all requirements are fulfilled.

When you run your app through fiddler and you see it downloading the uncompiled file, then that file is actually referenced from somewhere, because Cmd's build process and the uncompiled app are actually two distinct processes which both resolve the `requires` list of the files they touch, but are completely different code bases, actually. The order in which files are resolved in the uncompiled version may tell you from where the files are referenced.

As far as I know, Sencha Cmd does not have any way of specifically excluding files you don't want in your build; and I would guess you're gonna break something that way.

I have searched through the code and found that the following files require `Ext.form.field.Date`, which then requires `Ext.picker.Date`:

- `'Ext.form.field.Time'`
- `'Ext.grid.property.Grid'`

So if you have a timefield or a propertygrid in your code, ExtJS is correctly resolving and loading these files.